# Play all songs in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, audio-player

I'm using Python 3.8.2 and Windows. I have a problem. I am working on a project Audio Player. I wanted to create a Button that plays all the songs. When I use `pygame.mixer.music.play()` it doesn't start the song and wait till it's finished; it starts the song and moves to the next line.
So I can't put the code in a loop like this:

```
from pygame import *
list_of_songs = ['Guitar.mp3', 'song1.mp3', 'Piano.mp3']
for i in list_of_songs:
       init()
       mixer.init()
       mixer.music.load(i)
       mixer.music.play()
```

Is there a special command for that?

Comment: `mixer.music.queue()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pygame.mixer.music.queue()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.queue) for a playlist:

```py
list_of_songs = ['Guitar.mp3', 'song1.mp3', 'Piano.mp3']

for i, song in enumerate(list_of_songs):
    if i == 0:
        pygame.mixer.music.load(song)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.queue(song) 

while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Comment: Thank you all very much. It is working now. But can someone please explain me what `pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)` is?

Comment: @Tanmay You can think about is as "delay". See [`pygame.time.Clock().tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick)